# Feeding paramteres to a function as a list in R

Tags: r, spline, smoothing

I would like to compare different models and in order to save time I though about whether it is possible to feed in a list of values for a single argument in a function, and possibly plot the results.

My concrete example - I am interested in smoothing splines so the model is:

```
fit <- smooth.splines( x=train_x, y=train_y, df=seq(2, 20, by=0.5) )
```

which is all fine, but how do i select the different fits with via the "df"s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugly but you could do a loop

```
fits_out <- list()
for(i in 1:50){
fits[[i]] <- smooth.splines( x=train_x, y=train_y, df=i )
}
```

Then you can access each model fit from within the list object

Comment: R strongly encourages using `lapply` over a loop in such a case.

Comment: yeah this seems to work i will be doing this way, the problem is not too ahrs not to use something like this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I’m not entirely sure what you want to do but if you just want to just create splines with different degrees of freedom you need to iterate over them, `smooth.spline` is not vectorised in its `df` parameter:

```
fits = lapply(seq(2, 20, by = 0.5), smooth.spline, x = train_x, y = train_y, w = NULL)
```

Called like this, `lapply` will vary the `df` parameter; you can also write it more explicitly:

```
fits = lapply(
    seq(2, 20, by = 0.5),
    function (df) smooth.spline(x = train_x, y = train_y, df = df)
)
```